# Can't get the country from Facebook sdk 4.0 in android

Tags: android, facebook

I wrote an application in which I'm trying to get the country from Facebook sdk after pressing on the Facebook Login button :

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile,user_location,email,user_birthday,user_friends"));
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            result.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {


                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                     Log.v("Facebook response is", response.toString());    
                                     try
                                     {
                                          email = object.optString("email");
                                          fbid = object.optString("id");
                                             name=object.optString("name");
                                             firstname=object.optString("first_name");
                                             lastname=object.optString("last_name");
                                             gender=object.optString("gender");
                                             String l=object.optString("country");
                                        //   db.openDataBase();
                                           //db.update_value("info","gender",gender);
                                   //      db.close();

                                         thegender=gender;
                                         new Loginwithfacebook().execute();

                                          //  //makefacebookRequest(email,fbid,"no",gender);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"country is "+l,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                                     }
                                     catch(Exception ex)
                                     {
                                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
                                     }
                                   //  String name=obj.getString("name");
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();


                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,location,first_name,last_name,email,gender, birthday");
                  //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parameters.getString("email"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), gender,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
                } });
```

The message in the toast is "country is", The retrieving is failing, any help please ?

Comment: Test your request in Graph API Explorer first – that will show you what response you actually get from the API, and in what structure.

Comment: I've added this to the link : /me?fields=hometown,first_name,email,location

Everything is showing except Location, even when I change it to "country"

Comment: And what result does that request get you in Graph API Explorer? Also, pay attention to the debug messages GAE is showing.

Comment: {
  "hometown": {
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "ssasdasd"
  },
  "first_name": "ddas",
  "email": "ddasdsd@hotmail.com",
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxx"
}

Comment: And what about debug messages – none? If there are none, that simply means the user does not have a current location set.

Comment: yes there is no debug messages, do you know if there is a location set what is the name of the field under location ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no country field in the answer, so it can't be shown. If you're requesting the hometown.id which is in fact a page id of the location, it should return the country field (if it's set).

Otherwise, try

```
/me?fields=hometown,first_name,email,location{country}
```

Comment: doesn't work. location{location} is what works in Graph Explorer. but that also doesn't work through Android SDK.

Comment: Debug the used Access Token. I bet it doesn't contain the user_location permission

Comment: yes it does not but in request read permission array, it's present. but not in response. I have asked separate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306884/facebook-android-sdk-4-0-user-location

Comment: This permission is subject to Login Review from Facebook. Test with the app's admin/tester/developer users...