# Facebook Android SDK 4.0+ user_location?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, location, facebook-android-sdk, userlocation

I'm trying hard to get User's country but I'm not able to get it. Not able to understand what exactly is wrong here ?

I'm referring [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph) documentation. This is what I have tried so far -

```
public interface IFacebokLoginConstants extends ILoginConstants {

String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
String KEY_NAME = "name";
String KEY_LOCATION = "location{location}";
String[] READ_PERMISSIONS = {"public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_location"};
String[] WRITE_PERMISSIONS = {"publish_actions"};
String FIELD_KEY = "fields";

String FIELD_VALUE = KEY_ID + ","
        + KEY_FIRST_NAME + ","
        + KEY_LAST_NAME + ","
        + KEY_EMAIL + ","
        + KEY_LOCATION + ","
        + KEY_NAME;
}


   //---- inside activity
    mLoginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(WRITE_PERMISSIONS));

    mLoginManager.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Log.e(TAG, "LoginResult permissions: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getPermissions());

            Log.e(TAG, "LoginResult Denied Permissions: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getDeclinedPermissions());

            mUserId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();


            if (!loginResult.getAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("email")) {

                //--- current activity is  FacebookLoginActivity
            mLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(FacebookLoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList(READ_PERMISSIONS));
            } else {

                callUserInfoRequest(loginResult);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

            showShortToast("Login cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Error:  " + error.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

and this thing to retrieve user's info

```
private void callUserInfoRequest(LoginResult loginResult) {

    GraphRequest userInfoRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                    ///---- not receiving location information
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


                    try {
                        mUserName = object.getString(KEY_NAME);
                        mUserFirstName = object.getString(KEY_FIRST_NAME);
                        mUserLastName = object.getString(KEY_LAST_NAME);
                        mUserEmail = object.getString(KEY_EMAIL);


                        //after userInfo is acquired get profile image..
                        callProfileImageRequest();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    Bundle parametersBundle = new Bundle();
    parametersBundle.putString(FIELD_KEY, FIELD_VALUE);
    userInfoRequest.setParameters(parametersBundle);
    userInfoRequest.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32073757/3535399

Comment: @vivektakrani already tried this solution - location{location} as mentioned in comment in above code

Comment: Try your request in Graph API Explorer first, and see what exactly you get back, and in what structure. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Are you getting an error, or just an empty result? Not every user has the location set.

Comment: @CBroe i tried in graph API. it works for location{location}

Comment: @MingLi I'm getting response with first_name, last_name, email, id but location is missing and I'm trying for my own account. Location is present. i can see in graph explorer but not through this code.

Comment: Are you using a user access token from yourself in code? The user_location permissions requires your app to go through review, so if the user token is not an admin/developer/tester on the app, and your app hasn't gone through review yet, then you will not get that information.

Comment: @MingLi ohh so like publish_action even user_location needs approval ? So that means not just in code do I need to add it to app permissions where my app is registered?

Comment: That's correct, here's the list of permissions you can request, and under every permission it says whether it needs app review or not. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't have access to app in Facebook console, I wasn't sure about permissions requested by app. After discussion with @MingLi in above comments, I got to know that "user_location" permission needs approval from Facebook and it was not approved, though it was requested.

Above code started working after permission was granted by Facebook.